# How can I unzip files with "weird" extensions in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gzip

How can I unzip such files in ubuntu?
I have a list of files end with those extensions

```
filename.tar.gzaa  
filename.tar.gzab  
filename.tar.gzac  
filename.tar.gzad  
filename.tar.gzae  
filename.tar.gzaf
```

they have the same 'filename' with different suffix in extension.
And gzaa, to gzae has the same file size 1.1G and gzaf has a small file size.

I think all these files are 1 big zip file.

how can i unzip them?

Comment: Have you attempted using wildcards? What have you tried, and what happened? Also, what shell are you using?(I'm assuming Bash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the file extensions, it seems like you're trying to extract something you downloaded from Symantec. If so, run this:

```
cat filename.tar.gz* > temp.tar.gz
```

to combine the split files, and then

```
tar zxvf temp.tar.gz
```

to extract the resulting archive.

**Update**
It seems that the files are for Symantec Storage Foundation (link [here](https://www.symantec.com/storage-foundation)).

Sources: [this](https://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH55995) and [this](https://www.symantec.com/business/support/resources/sites/BUSINESS/content/live/TECHNICAL_SOLUTION/73000/TECH73186/en_US/329402.pdf)